# Obtaining a dictionary from string parts

Tags: json, string, dictionary, parsing

I'm wondering how to achieve the following thing:

I have a string version of a bibteX file (obtained through `requests` in the following representation:

```
'@article{blablabla,\n    key={\n\t1234567\n\t},\n    title={\n\tblablabla\n\t},\n    author={\n\t Name_of_the_authors \n\t},\n    journal={\n\t Name_of_the_journal \n\t},\n    volume={\n\t\n\t},\n    pages={\n\t\n\t},\n    year={\n\t 2020 \n\t},\n    url={\n\t DOI URL \n\t}\n}'
```

From this I would like to obtain a `dict` specifying the information that I need from above string, for example:

```
 dict1 = {author : 'Name_of_the_author', 'year' : 2020, 'url':'DOI URL'}
```

Maybe I could exploit the curly brackets for getting the information?

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most beautiful code to get there, but assuming your sample string in the question is representative of the actual data, one way to handle your problem is through some string manipulation:

```
data = """@article{blablabla,\n    key={\n\t1234567\n\t},\n    title={\n\tblablabla\n\t},\n    author={\n\t Name_of_the_authors \n\t},\n    journal={\n\t Name_of_the_journal \n\t},\n    volume={\n\t\n\t},\n    pages={\n\t\n\t},\n    year={\n\t 2020 \n\t},\n    url={\n\t DOI URL \n\t}\n}"""

data2=data.split(',')[1:]
targets = [2,-2,-1] #this is here because you're not interested in all the info in the string - but only 3 items

dict1={}
for target in targets:
    item=data2[target].replace('{\n\t','').replace('\n\t}','').strip().split("=")
    dict1[item[0]]=item[1].strip()
dict1
```

Output:

```
{'author': 'Name_of_the_authors', 'year': '2020', 'url': 'DOI URL \n}'}
```